# Prevent getaway to silently forward incoming packets

Tags: linux-networking, nat, gateway

I'm writing a NAT on Ubuntu 14.04 and in order to test if it's working as expected I manually changed the default getaway to the IP address at which the NAT is running for some of the other hosts belonging to the same net.

Despite I'm using raw sockets listening on IP 0.0.0.0 and I forced my NAT to accept just UDP packets over IPv4, from the program I wrote I'm not able to intercept the outgoing packets coming from any of the other hosts but the ones sent to broadcast addresses.

Trying to start a communication with netcat from one of the hosts and monitoring what is going on with wireshark I was able to see these packets.

What I would like to do is receiving these packets into my program and avoid that the system forward them out of my control. My assumption is that I'm missing something on the getaway and it could be just a matter of a configuration and should be independent by my program. How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not able to intercept the outgoing packets coming from any of the other hosts

This is how switched networks work. No NIC sees the (non-broadcast) traffic of other NICs, including the gateway.

> My assumption is that I'm missing something on the getaway

You are missing that *you* want to *be* the gateway.